# How to define an ESLInt rule for class attributes names?

Tags: eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am using javascript (not typescript) with eslint and airbnb rules.

I wonder if I can specify a rule to validate the naming of class attributes.

In particular, I would like to enforce that class attributes starts with "m_" and use snake case. example:

```
class A {
 constructor() {
   this.boo = "boo"; //BAD
   this.m_boo = "boo"; //OK
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only know of this (rather old) eslint plugin that has a rule similar to what you need, but you might be able to create your own custom rule based on this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-classes